# Search through multiple hosted XML files for a string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I'm working on a website that uses a lot of XML-files as data (150 in total and probably growing). Each page is an XML-file.

What I'm looking for is a way to look for a string through the XML-files. I'm not sure what programming language to use for this XML search engine.

I'm familiar with PHP, JavaScript, JQuery. So I'd prefer using those languages.

Thanks a bunch!

**UPDATE:** I'm looking for a solution that works quickly.

Ideally, the function returns the tagname that contains the searchstring.
If, for instance, the XML is as follows:

```
<article-1>This is a great story.</article-1>
```

If one would search for 'story', it would return 'article-1'.
I'm not quite sure on how to do this with a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can do this. Here's an example:

```
foreach(glob("{foldera/*.xml,folderb/*.xml}",GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
   //use regular expressions to find your string
}
```

You simply iterate through each file on your server using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Really nice. I will have a look. I've edited my question because I am curious about the speed of this solution.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm not sure on how to find the info using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem that could be solved with grep and regular expressions. Without knowing what string you're looking for it's not possible to say exactly what you should do, but reading some documentation on grep should get you started down the right path.