# Can I search all xml files in a directory for a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an aspx page that is using javascript/ jquery for a few functions. I have a directory with about 80 to 100 small XML files. I want to be able to search for the existence of a unique string (the string will only exist in one file and will be the text inside a node, not an attribute) . Then, once I get a match, I can get particular nodes I need from that file. I know how to get the info I need out of the XML file, but I need to get the file name of the match first. I found ways to do it in PHP here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762606/search-through-multiple-hosted-xml-files-for-a-string), but it has to be javascript for the existing project (or jquery, of course).

I suppose I could get all the file names of the dir, then loop each one them through a check, but seems like a lot. I was hoping some way to find a match first, then

```
function onMatch(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml", //the file with the match
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parceXML
    });
});
```

any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You can't point JavaScript code at an entire directory, only at specific files. Only server-side code can tell what files are in a server-side directory.

Comment: you would have to fetch every file using ajax to scour the contents, whereas with php you could only ship the files that have matches. if the folder gives a directory listing, you can ajax that landing page to a get a list of files names from ajax...

Comment: Thank you--wow that was fast. The page is .aspx. this may be a dumb question, but it is not possible to mix in php, is it?

Comment: aspx servers generally run php files just fine. try it. if not, you can use asp to do about anything php can, but you won't find as many asp examples...

Comment: I guess the issue that I have is that the call to find the the file exists in a js event that is called when a table cell is clicked. That is why I was hoping for a JS solution. I think I will have to find a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you do this in JavaScript? If you plan on grabbing many documents using ajax and parse them on the client side, it's very inefficient/slow.

You should have Javascript call a server side script on your server which looks at the xml files, figures out which one is the one you want and send you do the node you want.

Comment: Yes, that is the server side script I was hoping to figure out. Should mention I am a beginner